# Getting a black screenshot

Tags: android, scrollview, screenshot, android-bitmap

Basically, I want to take a screenshot of an entire scrollView. I've tried so many methods, but couldn't find the perfect one.

I've tried following:

```
public void takeScreenShot() {
    mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView();
    createImage(mbitmap);
}

public void createImage(Bitmap bmp) {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshot.jpg";
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapOFRootView() {
    mScrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    int totalHeight = mScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = mScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    mScrollView.layout(0,0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
    mScrollView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScrollView.getDrawingCache());
    mScrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return b;
}
```

This method almost works, but it's just showing me only 2 views and a button, other than that whole screen is black:

[image: Current ScreenShot]

my xml contains so many views, it's view hierarchy is something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
   <ConstraintLayout>
     <Views>
      ....
     <Views>
   </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've referred so many StackOverflow post, but it didn't work.
So can anybody help me with it?

**Update:**
Finally found a solution for it. So, it was an issue with the background, solved it by drawing canvas over it. Like below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
```

Comment: do you want to use this for automation? If so, your best shot might be: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#takeScreenshot().

Comment: Nope, I just want to take the screenshot of ScrollView and save it locally.

Comment: ok, your problem might be related to the fact that you are getting the bitmap from only the root view but not it's children. You would have to get all the bitmaps and then position them correctly afterward. The only other way I know to take a screenshot programmatically is using the UIDevice/UIAutomation but those should be used for testing, not in a production app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a canvas for the same

```
public static Bitmap saveBitmapFromView(View view, int width, int height) {
 Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
 view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
 view.draw(canvas);
 return bmp;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this too! Doesn't work!
Getting same output as above!

Answer (score 0):

### Taking and Sharing screenshot in android programmatically

***I've searched everywhere but found this one working***

**takeAndShareScreenshot()**

```
    private void takeAndShareScreenshot(){
        Bitmap ss = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(ss);
        shareIt();
    }
```

**takeScreenshot()**

```
    private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View view = // decore view of the activity/fragment;
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return view.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

**saveBitmap()**

```
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
// path to store screenshot and name of the file
        imagePath = new File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + "name_of_file" + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

**shareIt()**

```
private void shareIt() {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            String shareBody = getString(R.string.share_body_text);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.subject);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

#### Note:

```
In recent versions of android (>Marshmallow I guess), you may need `write 
access to external directory`
```